# Suppress folder not exist

Tags: powershell

This question is a part of a larger script that works as intended.
The problem is that the script fails if one of the folders missing.
I have tried different `if` statements, but it’s over my knowledge.

2 questions:

1. How can I suppress folders that missing in the script, so it not fails?
2. How can I get a separate logfile of missing folders?

This is the script:

```
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String[]]$IncludeFolders = @("Desktop", "Documents", "Pictures", "Videos", "Favorites")
)

#$IncludeFolders 
foreach ($IncludeFolder in $IncludeFolders) {
    & psexec ("\\" + $ServerUsersHome) -s -u $ServerUsersHomeUsername -p $ServerUsersHomePassword -w $ServerUsersHomeTempPath robocopy ($ServerUsersHomeFromPath + "\" + $IncludeFolder) ($ServerUsersHomeToPath + "\" + $IncludeFolder) $IncludeFiles /S /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /R:2 /W:5 /V /TEE ("/LOG+:" + $robocopylogfilename)
    Write-Log ("Remote executed robocopy completed. Exit code " + $LastExitCode) 5
} #IncludeFolders
```

Comment: Did you try using `Test-Path` to ensure the folder exists before trying to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Doing that in the code you have would make the commandline so convoluted that it's not even worth trying. Consider using `Invoke-Command` for running the loop on the remote host and use `Test-Path` for checking if a path exists.

```
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $ServerUsersHomePassword -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential $ServerUsersHomeUsername, $pw

Invoke-Command -Computer $ServerUsersHome -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location $using:ServerUsersHomeTempPath
    foreach ($IncludeFolder in $using:IncludeFolders) {
        $src = "${using:ServerUsersHomeFromPath}\${IncludeFolder}"
        if (Test-Path $src -Container) {
            & robocopy $src $using:IncludeFiles /S /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /R:2 /W:5 /V /TEE "/LOG+:${using:robocopylogfilename}"
        }
    }
} -Credential $cred
```

Q2: Add an `else` branch to the `if` statement in the above code where you write the information to a different file.

```
if (Test-Path $src -Container) {
    robocopy ...
} else {
    "Missing folder: ${src}" | Add-Content 'C:\path\to\missing_folders.log'
}
```